# Reg ex Python extract only before the first occurrence

Tags: python, regex

'''Reach out to your manager for further assistance. Context: I have not yet received my details.  Reach out to your HR for further assistance. Context: Reach out to your manager for further assistance. Context: I have not yet'''

I am new to regex and here I want to extract contents before the first occurrence of the word Context:

Current output:
Reach out to your manager for further assistance. Context: I have not yet received my details.  Reach out to your HR for further assistance. Context: Reach out to your manager for further assistance.

Desired output:
Reach out to your manager for further assistance.

I tried to use '''(.*?)Context:'''
but it is not stopping at first occurrence. Help me with this.

Comment: Why with regex? Just find the index where "Context" occurs, and slice from the string up to that point?

Comment: Are you using `re.findall`? Use `re.search` if you need the first match only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the built-in [split](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html) function, which would be the best solution in this case, or the [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) function from regular expressions.

```
string = '''Reach out to your manager for further assistance. Context: I have not yet received my details. 
Reach out to your HR for further assistance. Context: Reach out to your manager for further 
assistance. Context: I have not yet'''

# Using string slicing
str_sliced = string.split('Context: ')[0]
print(str_sliced)
# Output: Reach out to your manager for further assistance. 

# Using regular expressions
import re
pattern = r'Context: '
str_sliced = re.split(pattern, string)[0]
print(str_sliced)
# Output: Reach out to your manager for further assistance.
```